# Visual Studio 2017 creates empty solution for xamarin forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 creates empty solution (0 projects) for Xamarin.Forms.

How to resolve the problem please?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem as well recently and it seems [we are not alone as GitHub suggests](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1922). The problem surprisingly resolved itself for me by itself after VS repair and computer restart.

I recommend you to run the Visual Studio Installer and do a repair of VS as well. If it doesn't help, keep track of the GitHub discussion for workarounds.